# Update a component that is inside a p:tabView from a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, primefaces, updating

I have a problem referencing a component inside an ajax update so it can get updated.
Here`s the scenario.

[image: System View]

I have a **p:tabView** that has a dynamic creation of tabs.
Inside that tabView I have a **p:panel** and a **p:dataTable** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Brw.jpg).
In the panel I have a text field that needs to be updated called *cached-articles-text*.
When I check its id using firebug I see that it is **"tabs:0:cached-articles-text"**.

I need it to be updated on dataTable pagination. So inside the dataTable I have the following code:

```
<p:ajax event="page" update="something_goes_here"/>
```

That should update the text field.

How could I update that textField or the panel that contains the textField? The problem is that when I change the tab the id also changes:

**"tabs:0:cached-articles-text"**

**"tabs:1:cached-articles-text"**

**"tabs:2:cached-articles-text"**

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...
I`ve put the following in update and it worked.

```
<p:ajax event="page" update=":tab-form:abas:cached-articles-text"/>
```

But now I have another problem. The correct number of cached articles only shows when I make another request. Why is that?

Comment: I know this is old, but I am using PF5.3 and I get similar problems on updating a p:dataTable inside a p:tab inside a p:accordionView when I perform an update from a rowEdit. If I update the top-level accordion, it mangles the nested p:dataTable.